# Windows 8.1 Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro "Network Driver not properly installed"

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, lenovo-laptop

I've just received a brand new Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro just a few hours ago, and already there seems to be a problem. Windows 8.1 keeps telling me it cannot find any networks, and when I troubleshoot problems, it tells me that my drivers are not properly installed. I've reinstalled the drivers twice already, and even gotten the most up-to-date drivers from Lenovo's website. After taking a dive through the devices window, I can't even seem to locate the network adapter within it.

Am I missing something? Is it possible they forgot to install a network card (which in my lifetime, is unheard of! I mean, seriously!?)?

Comment: `I've just received a brand new Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro just a few hours ago, and already there seems to be a problem.` - This sounds like a perfect reason for contacting support.

Comment: I have contacted technicalsupport - It was a disgusting conversation. After 5 minutes of "Can you see the network adapter in the advanced devices window?", they just said "Return it" and redirected me to returns. I didn't wait 2 weeks for a brand new laptop that won't even run. If I absolutely have to return it, I will, but this is horrible.

Comment: I get your frustration but if it were me I would return it rather than waste any more time and effort on it.